# Git workflow - Merge master before or after pushing to public repo?

Tags: git, workflow

Here is what I have right now:

```
1 Github remote (origin)
2 Heroku (staging and production)
```

The workflow looks like follow:

First time (set up):

```
1 - Fork public Github (upstream) into public Github <br>
2 - Clone from public Github into local
```

Development workflow:

```
1 - Checkout feature-branch from local master
2 - After all commits, squash them
3 - Push that branch (with one commit) into origin
4 - Do a pull request to public Github
5 - Merge into public Github master
6 - Do a pull of master into local
7 - Do a rebase here??
8 - Push local master into Heroku Staging (do testing...)
9 - Push local master into Heroku Production
```

This is what they suggested me to do, but I have some doubts.  After doing the pull request and merge into public Github master (upstream), I do a pull of master into local, then why a rebase would make sense here? Shouldn't I do the rebase before pushing the feature-branch to origin?

Another doubt is, once I have done the pull from upstream master into the local branch, shouldn't I push that master into origin (my forked repository)?

**EDIT**: Here you can see the workflow in a diagram way: [Diagram workflow](http://oi49.tinypic.com/21ki2s8.jpg)

Thanks for clarifying these doubts.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, git rebase is dangerous for shared code. Rebasing is actually history re-writing which will also change the commit hashes. This means that git might think that a commit made in the past needs to be reapplied (when you are sharing code) and this can end up being a major headache. I avoid rebase most of the times.

I would prefer to have 2 different remote urls for origin. One for pushing and one for fetching. The fetching remote would be the main repository and the pushing remote would be the forked repository. This way you pull the latest master from the main repository, merge with a squash your branch, push the master branch into the forked repository and then just ask for the pull request.

You can set the url to the main repository like this:

`git remote set-url origin <main_repo_url_here>`

And afterwards, set the forked url only for pushes like this:

`git remote set-url --push origin <forked_personal_repo_url_here>`

You can check you results like this:

`git remote -v`

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  However it would be lovely to know if according to the workflow, the rebasing is being done correctly. I believe the rebase should be done before doing the pull request, but I am not sure...

Comment: In this case I will answer with another question: What do you want to rebase? Your (squashed) commits are already in the master branch of the upstream and after pulling you have the latest master branch which includes the feature-branch changes. So where is the need for a rebase?